# Slice/cherry-pick elements from n-D array using index from a (n-1)-D array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Here is an example

```
>>>a = np.array([[1,2],[3,5]])
>>>a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 5]])
>>>b = np.array([0, 1])
```

I am looking for a method to pick the 0th and 1st elements (depicted by array b) from the 0th and 1st row from array a as in:

```
>>>np.array([a[b[0]], a[b[1]]]) = np.array([1, 5])
```

Comment: My comment was deleted. Good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the so-called advanced indexing, this will do the job

`a[[0,1],[0,1]]`